# Logical Equivalences for "F" as a subset of the powerset of "A"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are these two statements equivalent?
Suppose F is a a subset of the powerset of A.
So $F \subseteq P(A)$
Then,

Statement 1: $  \forall x \in F(\forall y(y \in x \implies y \in A ))$

Is it not the case that this statement would also be equivalent?

Statement 2:
$\forall x \in F(x \in F \implies x \in A)$

Comment: x is a subset of $A$ hence it cannot be an element of $A$ you are comparing different objects

Comment: Statement 2 will become equivalent to Statement 1 if you replace it with $\forall x\in F(x\subseteq A)$ (i.e. replace $\in$ with $\subseteq$ and suppress the redundant "$x\in F\implies$").

Comment: thank you, that makes sense

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title. (It may include formulas.)

Comment: In "statement" 1, what are the brackets supposed to mean.  I usually wouldn't expect anything of the form "$\{....\}$" to be a statement at all.  I'd expect it to describe a set with "$....$" being a description.  If I were to interpret $\forall x\in F(\forall y(y\in x\implies y\in A))$ as a description of elements (to be honest I'm not sure if that is gramatically acceptable or not), then 1 is not a statement at all but merely a description of a subset of $F$ (which would happen to be $F$ itself).

Answer (score 2):

No, without even reading what F is, we can tell from $\forall y$, if $y \in x$ then $y \in A$, that $x \subset A$, as any element in x appears in A as well. Because x is a *subset* of A, x is not inherently an element of A. For example, consider $$A = \{1,2,3,4,5\} \\ x = \{1,2,3\}$$ here, x is clearly not an element of A. The elements of x, namely 1,2,3, all appear in A but the set x istself does not ($\{1, 2, 3\} \not \in A$). But if we set $A = \{1,2,3,4,5, \{1,2,3\}\}$, x is now an element of A, as we can clearly see that x is inside of A. Statement 2 would be correct if it was changed to $$\forall x( x \in F \rightarrow x \subset A)$$ And we had previously defined $F \subseteq P(A)$.

Also, in the comments someone wrote that $x \subseteq A$, which is (to my knowledge) improper notation, as $\subseteq$ is a proper subset meaning x cannot equal A, which is not the case here.